# List strings not found with grep

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep

I want to search in a file for specific words and then show only the words that were not found. So far, with my limited skills in this area, I can find which words are found:

```
egrep -w "^bower_components|^npm-debug.log" .gitignore
```

If my **.gitignore** file contained **bower_components** but not **npm-debug.log** it would return **bower_components**. I want to find out how to ask it to return only the part of the pattern that was not found. That is, I want it to return only **npm-debug.log**. I don't want to see all of the text from the file that does not match the search, only the single word from the file that was not found. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a one liner for you but a short script would work for your use case.

```
file=$1
shift
for var in "$@"
do
  found=`grep "^$var" $file`
  if [[ -z $found ]]
  then
   echo $var
  fi
done
```

Explanation, take the first argument as the file name, any subsequent arguments as strings to test for in the file. Loop through those arguments and test the result of the grep command to see if it returned empty. If it did then the string wasn't found and we print it to the console.
Usage: `[script name] .gitignore bower_components npm-debug.log`

Comment: I need to tweak the answer slightly and found it easiest to tweak this nicely laid out and easy to read bash script.

Answer (score 3):

If you have just simple words like in your example, you could do it with two `grep` commands in one-liner. For example:

**file:**

```
first line
_another line
just another line
STRANGE LINE
last line
```

**words:**

```
first
last
row
other
^another
LINE$
```

we can first get the matched patterns

```
> grep -owf words file
first
LINE
last
```

and then we `grep -v` for them in `words`. Also add a `uniq` in the middle to remove any duplicates.

so finally we get patterns from `words` not matched in `file`:

```
> grep -owf words file | uniq | grep -vf - words
row
other
^another
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this can be done with grep alone; here's a clumsy awk one-liner:

```
awk -v p1="npm-debug.log" -v p2="bower-component" 'BEGIN{a[p1]=0;a[p2]=0} $0 ~ p1 {a[p1]+=1}; $0 ~ p2 {a[p2]+=1}; END{for(i in a){if( a[i]==0){print i}}}' .gitignore
```

I'm passing the search pattern into awk as variables, pre-populating an array using the patterns as index, incrementing them if they match and only print ones that didn't have hits (still are 0).